# update table using data from listview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Public Sub FeesFromSetFeesContinuous(ByRef lst As ListView, ByRef txtAmt As TextBox, ByRef txtYear As TextBox, ByRef cboClass As ComboBox, ByRef cboTerm As ComboBox, cboMode As ComboBox, toText As TextBox, add As TextBox)
    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If
        Dim id As New TextBox
        Dim bal As New TextBox
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        For Each item As ListViewItem In lst.Items
            id.Text = item.SubItems(0).Text
            bal.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text
            sql = "update fees set class='" & cboClass.Text & "'," &
                  "year ='" & txtYear.Text & "'," & "mode='" & cboMode.Text & "'," &
                  "term ='" & cboTerm.Text & "'," &
                  "balance='" & bal.Text & "'" & "where id = '" & id.Text & "'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            MessageBox.Show("done")
        Next

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I get my message as done but nothing really changes or affect the data in the table. Please any help

Comment: I suggest you do a debug session and break just before the ExecuteNonQuery.  Then use the Immediate Window and query the value in the sql variable (?sql).  Cut and Paste the result into sql and see what it does.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting error.  If your code does throw an exception, you aren't closing the connection.  Put your disposable objects in a Using - End Using block to avoid that.  ExecuteNonQuery will return the number of rows affected, so if it's greater than zero, the query worked..

Comment: Why would you create local TextBox variables, just to store strings? (just use strings). Why pass the variables ByRef? (you aren't updating them but they are objects anyway so it's nonsensical). You should make a new connection in a Using block instead of holding one at the class level. Use parameters instead of passing UI controls, and even if you don't use parameters, don't pass UI controls; pass the strings instead.

Comment: But to solve your problem, what type is `fees.id`? You are passing `item.SubItems(0).Text` into the `WHERE` clause but you enclose it in single quotes. Is the id a string? Maybe you just need to remove the single quotes in the query.

Comment: Folks, thanks for your suggestions and answers, I really appreciate it. I will try and give you feedback on your answers. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT pass controls. DO NOT pass them ByRef. Pass just values you want to use. I guess you got tired of typing ByRef at the end of the argument list. I don't think the last two are even used.

Keep your database objects local so you can control their closing and disposing. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for you.

Don't store values in invisible text boxes. Use variable.

You are creating a new string and a new command for every iteration of you For loop. This is very inefficient.

Use Parameters to avoid Sql Injection. There are only 2 parameters that change their values. Add all the parameters only once to the command. The value of most of them are set only once. Only the two that change are set in the loop.

You are showing the "done" message box on every iteration of your loop. Never show a message box while your connection is open. Your user could have gone to lunch and won't respond to the message box until they return.

Create a Data Access class as follows.

```
Public Class Fees
    Public Sub FeesFromSetFeesContinuous(IDList As List(Of String), BalanceList As List(Of String), Amt As String, Year As String, Clss As String, Term As String, Mode As String)
        Dim Sql = "Update fees Set class = @Class, year = @Year, mode = @Mode,
              term = @Term, balance = @Balance where id = @ID;"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, cn)
                With cmd.Parameters
                    .Add("@Class", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Clss 'Class is a word in the language
                    .Add("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Year
                    .Add("@Mode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Mode
                    .Add("@Term", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Term
                    .Add("@Balance", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    .Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                End With
                cn.Open()
                For index = 0 To IDList.Count - 1
                    cmd.Parameters("@Balance").Value = BalanceList(index)
                    cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = IDList(index)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("done")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then in the User Interface (the Form)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lstId As New List(Of String)
    Dim lstBalance As New List(Of String)
    For Each li As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        lstId.Add(li.SubItems(0).ToString)
        lstBalance.Add(li.SubItems(1).ToString)
    Next
    Dim f As New Fees()
    Try
        f.FeesFromSetFeesContinuous(lstId, lstBalance, txtAmt.Text, txtYear.Text, cboClass.Text, cboTerm.Text, cboMode.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

You will need to check the database to get the correct field datatypes an adjust the code accordingly. Redo the SqlDbType values and Convert any strings as necessary. Since you enclosed all the values in single quotes I assumed VarChar (strings) but I suspect that at least id, balance, and year might be numeric types.

Comment: @LarsTech I didn't add checks for length an equality of length for the 2 lists but if there is something else, I am just not seeing it. Slower than usual today. Please point out my errors. I have tested and still can't see it. Thanks.